# Why does .save call model validation on attributes not being updated?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User model and I'm writing a method to update the email authentication token. When I try to call on the method with a user object it would raise validation error that password submitted is blank. User object was saved already and has been found and called the gen_token method from the controller (ex: user.gen_token). Part of my code looks like the following:

```
#controller
user.gen_token
#User model
validates :password, presence: true
def gen_token
  self[:email_token]=SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  save!
end
```

My question is why is the validation on password raised when I'm only updating User Model's email_token attribute?

The error is as follows:
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password confirmation can't be blank

I also realized that if I remove save!, the code works correctly as I want that it will update the email_token. Now I'm wondering if calling save or update_attribute is necessary at all in Model since you can just change the attribute by doing self[attribute]=new_value.

Comment: can you show us the error?

Comment: Updated. Please see my error. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

.save call all the validation on object.
if you want to skip validation then use update_column method or update_attribute method to update the email_token.
You can also add condition on your validation like

> validates :password, presence: true, on: :create